Calculating TWAP for Transaction Cost Analysis
I am looking to perform TCA of several orders.
I would normally look to calculate an order's VWAP/ TWAP only relative to the executions of that order.
So for instance, calculating an order's TWAP (with 3 executions)as simply (ExecPrice1 + ExecPrice2 + ExecPrice3) / 3.
However, the more I think about it, I am starting to question if I should take other executions in the market that took place over the order's lifetime, or if this is enough, and the 'market' aspect of the order would be covered by taking the Arrival Price as the price as of the order start time.
